# jQuery ajax: loading html + applying plugin, ie7

Tags: jquery, ajax, smart-wizard

I have a part of a page that i want to load using ajax. The content is the html for this wizard: http://techlaboratory.net/labs/SmartWizard2/index.htm

What im currently doing:

```
$(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'content.htm',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {

            $('#content').html(data);

            $('#wizard').smartWizard({

            //#wizard is inside the #content

                transitionEffect:'fade', 
                onFinish: function() { 
                    alert('finishClicked');
                } 

            });


        }
    });

});
```

The script works fine if i just use $('#wizard').smartWizard(), and keep everything on the same page. But when im loading with ajax it doesnt work. Could anyone tell me the difference? Any ideas how to solve? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot do ajax requests on different domains due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

There are a few solutions to overcoming this. Take a look through here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Same+Origin+Policy